# heroku mailer with google apps telling me to sign in via web browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, google-apps

I setup google apps and heroku to send mail. I sent the first mail from within my app and everything is great. Then, I changed the email on my google apps account (from matt@website.com to team@website.com)...made sure to change it in heroku config settings...restarted...but now it gives me this error:

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535-5.7.1 Please log in with your web browser and then try again. Learn more at
```

I tried logging in via the web browser and everything is fine. I just keep getting this same error when I try to send mail now.

Answer (score 0):

This should help: http://www.rocketideas.com/2012/05/gmail-error-password-not-accepted-from-server-solved/

I've tested it and it works for me.